# Beeline/Hive/Hadoop stops (big delay) in a simple DESC-table command

Tags: hadoop, hive, wait

At Beeline shell, the command

```
 DESC db.t
```

is, in normal conditions, **fast** (instantaneous) for any *Hive Managed table*. DESC is a pure-metadata-command, so I suppose that it depends only on Metastore (in our case Derby)...  Now, some days, perhaps with a lot of users, the command DESC  not respond, Beeline stops (waiting 2, 5 or more minutes).  Seems a "bug" in the infrastructure, **it is a Derby problem?** Any knowed/reported problem?

---

Versions: Beeline 1.2 connected to Hive 1.2.1000.2 and Hadoop 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

HiveServer2 has (had until version 2.+, see [HIVE-4239](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4239)) a lock that serializes compilation of all queries received from the clients, including beeline. Most likely, you're observing the effects of this queuing, although I won't exclude possible Derby problems either :) Review of a HS2 logs should help with definitive diagnosis.